Saving passwords for multiple sites in Chrome
Strictly for internal sites, I have the same login credentials for all the sites. Think single sign-on within the organization. I have been having Chrome save the passwords for the sites but it seems to be somewhat random on how the passwords are saved. I may have a group of 4-6 sites saved with the password and another group saved with the same username/password.
When I enter the Chrome password manager, I can see the various saved entries. My first preference would be to edit the sites that a given entry applies to but this does not seem to be an option.
My fallback options would be to have Chrome save the same username/password for all of *.example.com sites. It would be helpful if I could be presented with a choice of two usernames for a given site but this is not strictly necessary.
